# Find order of an element in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suddenly  a question has cropped up in my mind  which I can't answer on my own:

If $x\in \oplus_p \mathbb Z_p$ where $p$ is a prime i.e if $x$ is in the direct product of cyclic groups will order of $x$ be finite?

Comment: First of all, what you wrote is a direct **sum** of cyclic groups. Any element of such a direct sum will have finite order. However, there are elements in the direct product that have infinite order.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $x$ will have finite order, as $x= \sum x_p$ for $x_p\in \mathbb Z_p$ and only finitely many of those nonzero. Then $x$ gets annihilated by the product of those $p$ such that $x_p\neq 0 $

Comment: The situation would be different in the direct *product* instead of direct *sum*, i.e., when we no longer require that almost all components are zero

Comment: This is the definition of the direct sum: $\bigoplus G_i =\{ (g_i): g_i\in G_i, \texttt {only finitely many } g_i\neq 0\}$. As mentioned above, the direct product does not have this property, as $\prod G_i =\{ (g_i): g_i\in G_i\}$ without the finiteness. Then for example the element $(1,1,\ldots)$ has infinite order

Comment: please do it for the case when all may be non-zero;there may be a problem in the terminology

Comment: Do you see why $(1,1,\ldots)$ has infinite order in $\prod \mathbb Z_p$?